# elRTE error 0x80004005 in Firefox

Tags: javascript, jquery, wysiwyg, html-editor

```
Error: uncaught exception: [Exception... 
"Component returned failure code: 0x80004005 
(NS_ERROR_FAILURE) [nsIDOMNSHTMLDocument.execCommand]"  
nsresult: "0x80004005 
(NS_ERROR_FAILURE)"  
location: "JS frame :: http://localhost/mypage/admin/elrte/js/elrte.min.js
 :: <TOP_LEVEL> :: line 34"  data: no]
```

Why am I getting this error in Firefox, with the elRTE plugin? I didn't try it in other version of Firefox. But in Firefox 5 I'm getting this error?

Comment: Show the code where you load all JS scripts and where you initialize elRTE.  Link to the page in question or paste its source code at paste.bin

Answer (score 1, accepted):

display:none in style parent div occurs this problem, I explain what I want to say in here,

http://elrte.org/redmine/boards/4/topics/3279